What does "hot" mean in "there's an old piano and they play it hot behind the green door"?
This context comes from the movie "Once Upon a Time in Hollywood"
It's a scene in which Leonardo Dicaprio is singing a song with female dancers around him on a stage of some kind of a television show. This recording (which was referred to as a kinescope in the movie) was sent to a director (played by Al Pacino) interested in putting him in a movie of his own.
"There's an old piano and they play it hot behind the green door"
What does the word "hot" mean in this context? Is it an adjective or adverb?

good. (adj):
"this is not so hot for business" (Oxford Leaners Dictionary)

(of popular music) strongly rhythmical and excitingly played. (adj):
"hot salsa and lambada dancing" (Oxford Leaners Dictionary)

Rapidly, quickly.(adv)(Wiktionary)


Ps. The word "hot" is one of those words that remain very delusive and illusive in many contexts for me after so many years of learning the language.

deluvise? Maybe deluding.

@Lambie delusive means 'tending to mislead' and this is what I meant.

Probably an unlikely meaning, but to "play it hot" could be a playful hyperbole of how much and how quickly they play the piano - to play the piano so hard and so much that it "heats up" / is played until it becomes hot (in temperature).

Short answer? Yes, the #2 musical meaning of "hot."

Song lyrics are poetry, and poetry often bends usage rules. As long as you take the intended meaning, it's often not worth interrogating the structure too rigorously.
This song is "Green Door." Especially given the possibility that it's referencing a 1920s setting, "hot" is probably used with meanings that it often carries in jazz settings. See this pdf that describes "cool jazz" and sets it against "bebop"; "hot jazz" is also associated with Dixieland. Broader uses of "hot" evolved out of these into the cultures of other musical genres, like "hot licks" on rock guitar.

Combining this with a lenient reading of the sentence structure, we might paraphrase it as:

Somewhere there is a green door, behind which is a club in which they play an old piano in a "hot" style.

